# facebook iframe application redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

I have made an iframe style facebook application that uses php and javascript (jquery). When a browser is looking at my canvas page how do I redirect their browser window to a url?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reference the window 'top'

```
window.top.location.href="your link here";
```

That will ensure you break out of any iframes.